# why the result is inconsistent with expected in this decorate function?

Tags: javascript, function, firefox

This is a chain function call, I expect that all the output block between '--------' and next '---------' should be exactly same, but when I try running it, the content between first block' ------' of the output is different from all the following block of output?

The first two lines of output is:

```
function(){alert('original')}
function(){alert('original')}
--------------
```

the following are:

```
function(){alert('original')}
function m(){
    console.log(f.toString());
    console.log(fun1.toString());
    console.log('--------');

    return m; 
}
--------------
.... (repeat)
--------------
```

the code is following:

```
<script>
var fun1 = function(){alert('original')};
function decoratefun (f){
    return (function m(){
        console.log(f.toString());
        console.log(fun1.toString());
        console.log('--------');

        return m; 
    })();
}

var fun1 = decoratefun(fun1);

fun1()()()(); 
</script>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Which browser are you using? What output are you getting? Why do you expect it to be the same?

Comment: @Bergi I am using firefox with firebug plugin, as it is writing to console, I think firebug or some plugin is needed to display the result. because I am printing string format of fun1 and f during each block.

Comment: I thought Firefox' builtin console would now be capable of doing that, but regardless: Again I have to ask: **What output *are* you getting** that is unexpected? Please [edit] it into your question.

Comment: @Bergi thx, I updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first invocation of `m` happens inside the invocation of `decoratefun(fun1)`. It will log the function `f` and the *current* value of `fun1`, which has not yet been reassigned to become `m`.

To "fix" this, use

```
function decoratefun (f){
    return function m(){
        console.log(f.toString());
        console.log(fun1.toString());
        console.log('--------');

        return m; 
    };
//   ^ no invocation here
}
```

instead